# What is the "initialization time" in the find command?

Tags: shell, find

When I try to refer find command's man page , I come across

```
-mmin n
        The value of n can be one of the following:
          n
               Evaluates as True if the file modification time subtracted from the initialization time, divided by 60 seconds (with any remainder discarded), is
               n.
          -n
               Evaluates as True if the file modification time subtracted from the initialization time, divided by 60 seconds (with any remainder discarded), is
               less than n.
          +n
               Evaluates as True if the file modification time subtracted from the initialization time, divided by 60 seconds (with any remainder discarded), is
               greater than n (in case of UNIX03, greater than n+1).
        Note: Files modified after the find command start time will not be taken into account. However, when the find command is used within the unary NOT
        operator for non-UNIX03 behavior, the files modified after the command start time will be displayed until the value of n.
   -mtime n
        The value of n can be one of the following:
          n
               Evaluates as True if the file modification time subtracted from the initialization time, divided by 86400 seconds (with any remainder discarded),
               is n. 86400 seconds is 24 hours.
          -n
               Evaluates as True if the file modification time subtracted from the initialization time, divided by 86400 seconds (with any remainder discarded),
               is less than n.
          +n
               Evaluates as True if the file modification time subtracted from the initialization time, divided by 86400 seconds (with any remainder discarded),
```

What is this initialization time? Is this the time when find command got invoked?

Comment: What OS is this find on? I do not have this in the GNU version on Fedora. Is this AIX? http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds2/find.htm

Comment: @slm Apologies for not mentioning that it is AIX 6.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. The “initialization time” is a particular time after the `find` command starts and before it starts processing any file. It's a common time origin, to avoid the outcome of time-based comparisons to depend on the order in which files are traversed.

“Initialization time” is the term used in the [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html). [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=find&sektion=1) calls it “the time `find` was started”. GNU and Solaris don't document it but also use a time origin.

Answer (score 0):

time offsets relate to now, unless you use the option to mean start of current day (00:00)

Comment: What's _now_? Is it the date the of the `execve` system call that started `find`, or of a `gettimeofday()` system call made by `find` later on, or of a `gettimeofday()` system call just after or before the `lstat()` system call made on the file that is to be checked against mtime/mmin?

Comment: *Initialization* time would be from when find *starts*, as contrasted to when it happens to stat() any particular file.

Comment: @goldilocks - are you saying that is what it definitely is or what you think it is? Makes sense just couldn't confirm this in any official way, but I don't have access to AIX so it's a bit of a crap shoot.

Comment: I think if that's *not* what it means, then this a bug in the documentation.  What else can "initialization time" (reasonably) be taken to refer to?  Surely not (e.g.) "the initialization time of a `struct stat` used to profile a particular file"?  Surely the term *initialization time* is used so there won't be any such confusion??  It's the initialization time of `find`, i.e., sometime in the first second or so.